# Управление документом, вне фокуса

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Сделал скрипт управлением страницей,тыкает на кнопки и т.д.(автопокупка стим,если кому интересно). TamperMonkey.

Так вот вопрос,чтобы управлять страницей через скрипт,она  непременно должна быть открыта во вкладке.У меня таких вкладок получается очень много и нужно ещё больше.

Так вот вопрос,можно ли проделывать то же самое но не с кучей открытых вкладок,которые переодически нужно обновлять.(например сделать специальную хтмл страничку).Просто не знаю,а чтобы загуглить даже не знаю,что вбить в поисковик(выходит один бред).

Есть такое расширение для автоматической покупки,но оно же работает при закрытых вкладках.

P.s.Дело не в самом стиме,про расширение для этого знаю и про встроенную функцию тоже.

Comment: не совсем понятен вопрос. но думаю , что можно попробовать сделать на одной вкладке через `iframe`

Comment: Почему непонятен?
Попробую ещё одну аналогию провести.
Имеем 100 групп вк и на каждой из них надо каждые 100секунд например,нажимать на кнопку(любую,неважно зачем).
Короче говоря работать открытой вкладкой.
Так вот через TamperMonkey со скриптом на борту это делается только при открытых вкладках,а 100 вкладок это много.
Хотелось бы то же самое,но при меньших вкладках :)
p.s не воспринимайте всерьёз поставленную в этом сообщении задачу,это лишь для большего понимания сути,что нужно сделать.